Create and manage object/variable inside worker in Celery
I have a configuration with a couple of Celery workers. I hope that each worker executes exactly one task (although there are a couple of child processes), that is, each user is connected to a worker.
Is it possible for each worker to create an object on worker creation, pass it to each task it handles, recreate the object once the task is executed (successfully or not) and delete the object once the worker is deleted or restarted?
The more difficult question: is it possible to create global list of objects and control creation between workers (some sort of a pool)?
Thank you.
